# grab multiple custom attr value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to grab DataId, DataType, DataType this 3 custom attribute value as per button click. I already coded jquery like bellow but this not works at all. Any idea to fix it?

Table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>P Status</th>
            <th>P Sub Status</th>
            <th>T Lead</th>
            <th>P Status Order</th>
            <th>P Sub Status Order</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>In Process - ASPN</td>
                <td>
                    Benefits Verification 
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" DataId="1" DataType="ProgramSubstatus" DataValue="Benefits Verification " style="float:right;margin-left:5px;">Edit</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                Jelsa Nichols
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" DataId="1" DataType="TeamLead" style="float:right;margin-left:5px;">Edit</button>
        </td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("button").on("click", "button", function () {
            var DataId = $(this).attr("DataId");
            var DataType = $(this).attr("DataType");
            var DataValue = $(this).attr("DataValue");

            console.log(DataId);
            console.log(DataType);
            console.log(DataType);
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: `Try $("button").click(function() {..` instead. Also you should probably use [data- attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) to make it valid.

Comment: if you are binding to dynamically created buttons then you need to change the first selector (the one before the `.on`) to `.table` or `document` otherwise you can bind as h77 says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have referenced the `button` selector twice -

```
$("button").on("click", "button", function () {})
//---^here-----------------^here---
```

This means that you are actually adding a `click` event handler to any `button` that is *inside* a `button` (a descendant) . Since you don't have a button within a button in your HTML, you're not able to catch that event being fired.

To solve this, you need to remove the inner reference to `button`. That will leave you with something that looks like this -

```
$("button").on("click", function () {})
```

In [the documentation for the `on` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/), it mentions that the 2nd parameter is a selector (emphasis was added) -

> `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`
>
> `selector`
>   Type: String
>   A selector string to **filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event.** If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

---

In addition, I would recommend taking a look at the recommended way to use the `data-*` attributes. You don't need to access them as you do for a normal attribute. Please take a moment to read over this page of the docs - https://api.jquery.com/data/

As an example (lifted from the linked docs) -

```
<div  
   data-role="page" 
   data-last-value="43" 
   data-hidden="true" 
   data-options='{"name":"John"}'>
</div>

$( "div" ).data( "role" ) === "page";
$( "div" ).data( "lastValue" ) === 43;
$( "div" ).data( "hidden" ) === true;
$( "div" ).data( "options" ).name === "John";
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add about custom `data-*` attribute to persists arbitrary data

Answer (score 0):

change the button to document it will work fine

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on("click", "button", function () {
        var DataId = $(this).attr("DataId");
        var DataType = $(this).attr("DataType");
        var DataValue = $(this).attr("DataValue");

        console.log(DataId);
        console.log(DataType);
        console.log(DataType);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $("button").on("click", function () {
// do stuff
})
```

You just need the button selector once.